# close ssh sessions

Tags: ssh

I'm using ~/.ssh/config for logging to the `internal.local` corporate server:

```
Host internal.local
    ProxyCommand ssh -e none corporate.proxy nc %h %p
```

But after closing session (typing `exit`), my sshd session on server stays still active (I see it through different connection).

Hot do I close session or change my config in the appropriate way, to eleminate hang sessions?

First check from the second, root session: `ps -fu user_name`

```
user_name 861   855   0 16:58:16 pts/3       0:00 -bash
user_name 855   854   0 16:58:13 ?           0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
```

After logging out:

```
user_name 855   854   0 16:58:13 ?           0:00 /usr/lib/ssh/sshd
```

Just after `scp` files to/from the `internal.local` a new `scp` sessions still hangs on the server.

Comment: You might have some processes still running in the SSH session. The connection will stay up until they finish.

Comment: Just `ssh internal.local` then `exit`.

Comment: thanks for mention „-e none“ sometimes ~. is usefull, but most time it sucks to type „~ “ to type a tilde. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
# for Solaris
ProxyCommand ssh -e none corporate.proxy nc %h %p -c
```

or

```
# for *nix
ProxyCommand ssh -e none corporate.proxy nc %h %p -w 5
```

`-c` cause to close connection after doing work on Solaris, and `-w` is the same on *nix systems.